# Flutter appbar Row independent alignment

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-appbar

I've been trying to achieve this alignment in a flutter AppBar:
[image]

I tried doing it in multiple ways, with Flex (which didn't really work, all the widget got clustered together) and with static paddings...

Flex:
Don't know why my sizedBoxes expand... Also I don't know how to align the button, dropdown and drawer to the left...

[image]

```
AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      title: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Flexible(
            fit: FlexFit.tight,
            flex: 4,
            child: Container(
              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary,
              child: Column(
                children: const [
                  Image(
                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/danube_logo.png'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            fit: FlexFit.tight,
            flex: 6,
            child: Container(
              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary,
              child: Column(
                children: const [
                  Image(
                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/eu_logo.png'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const Flexible(
            fit: FlexFit.tight,
            flex: 2,
            child: MyTripsButton(),
          ),
          const Flexible(
            fit: FlexFit.tight,
            flex: 2,
            child: LanguageSelector(),
          ),
          const Flexible(
            fit: FlexFit.tight,
            flex: 2,
            child: DrawerMenuButton(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Paddings, kinda work but not the best solution...:
[image]

```
 AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 13.0, right: 130.0),
                child: Container(
                  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary,
                  child: Column(
                    children: const [
                      Image(
                        fit: BoxFit.contain,
                        image: AssetImage('assets/images/danube_logo.png'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary,
                child: Column(
                  children: const [
                    Image(
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                      image: AssetImage('assets/images/eu_logo.png'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 25.0),
                child: const MyTripsButton(),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 50.0),
                child: const LanguageSelector(),
              ),
              Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    right: 30.0,
                  ),
                  child: DrawerMenuButton()),
            ],
          ),
        );
```

Am I going around this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Just use two row widgets. Wrap your 2 left widgets within one row and other widgets in the second row. After this wrap both of your rows into a parent row and give the property of `spaceBetween`. Not the best solution but it will work